# Menu below the logo

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to create a menu similar to [this](http://hellomarcus.com/profile/) (try in mobile mode):

In "desktop" mode, I want the brand logo and other words on the left, and the menu on the right.
In "mobile" mode, I would a block with the logo and other words, and below the menu that should take the whole row.

Any suggestion to obtain this result?

Link to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/818/)

As you can see I defined some CSS ids, just to have:

```
display:block
```

One for the container of the logo+words (on the left) and one for the container of the menu (on the right).

It does not work as I would, because I do not know how to put the menu below the brand's name when I am in mobile mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is the result you are looking for:

The CSS to add

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
  #nav-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .navbar-header button {
    float:none;
    margin:15px 0px;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/821/)

If you want the menu above, invert the html blocks `id="nav-logo"` and `id="logo"`... [the updatade JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/822/)

Comment: Or you can also use css [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to change the order of your logo and nav - http://jsfiddle.net/8ompfhtm/